# Getting error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol when compiling SDL2 code in Windows using MSVC

Tags: visual-c++, sdl, linker-errors, sdl-2

The complete error output:

```
SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CommandLineToArgvW referenced in function main_getcmdline
```

My compiler options:

```
cl -D WINDOWS -nologo -W4 -WX -wd4100 -Fe"output_file.exe" input_file.c SDL2.lib SDL2main.lib -I ./SDL2-2.0.12/include -link -LIBPATH:./SDL2-2.0.12/lib/x64 -SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

My `input_file.c` header and main function:

```
#ifdef LINUX
#include <SDL2/SDL.h> /* Comes with stdio.h and stdlib.h */
#elif WINDOWS
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                                              {
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO|SDL_INIT_TIMER) != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return -1;
  }

. . .
```

The SDL development folder used in the command line arguments is the development libraries zip file downloaded from libsdl.org

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: [CommandLineToArgvW()](https://docs.microsof.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) is a WinAPI function found in `ShellAPI.h` and located in `Shell32.dll`.

Comment: I added Shell32.lib to the command line arguments and it works! Thanks man!

Comment: I just want to know why I didn't find that anywhere. Why no one tells to add Shell32.dll when compiling SDL program on windows.

Comment: I can't answer that, I'm afraid. I don't use SDL. I just recognized the function name when I read the error message and knew where to look for the docs. :-) Glad I could help.

Comment: @serafimeid https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/windows-build-fails-with-missing-symbol-imp-commandlinetoargvw/27256 this change is not that old, articles you read are probably older. Still it probably should be added to FAQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you also need to use the library called "shell32.lib" 
`cl -D WINDOWS -nologo -W4 -WX -wd4100 -Fe"output_file.exe" input_file.c shell32.lib SDL2.lib SDL2main.lib -I ./SDL2-2.0.12/include -link -LIBPATH:./SDL2-2.0.12/lib/x64 -SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`

Comment: Yeah man, I got it from a comment to the question, but much thanks anyway!! Also someone in the comments sent a link of this error saying that now SDLmain requires linking to the Shell32.lib.